# How to Use Word Wrap in Angular UI Grid

Tags: angular

I am Using Angular UI Grid . 
I am not able to use word wrap in my table cell. 
Can somebody help me regarding this

[UI Grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yk54C.png)

Comment: Can you share code what you have done so far??

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Answer (score 1):

If you override the text-overflow property using clip you can remove the ellipses without overflowing the text.

```
.ui-grid-header-cell .ui-grid-cell-contents {
   height: 90px;
   -ms-text-overflow: clip;
   -o-text-overflow: clip;
   text-overflow: clip;
 }
```

Note, you can also disable the v with

```
.ui-grid-icon-angle-down::before {
  content: none;
}
```